# How to extend component with ChangeDetectorRef one of its dependencies

Tags: angular, kendo-ui, kendo-grid

I'm trying to extend a component and one of its dependencies is `ChangeDetectorRef`

```
export class BgridComponent extends GridComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() exportFileName: string = '';

  constructor(
    ...,
    changeDetectorRef: ChangeDetectorRef,
    ...
  ){
    super(
      ...,
      changeDetectorRef,
      ...
    )
  }
}
```

and there is always this error:

```
ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[BgridComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[BgridComponent -> ChangeDetectorRef]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for ChangeDetectorRef!
```

Answer (score 0):

You'd have to inject the `ChangeDetectorRef` in your child as well. For example:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'child',
  // ...
})
export class ChildComponent extends ParentComponent {
  constructor(cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {
    super(cd);
  }
}
```

```
@Component({
  selector: 'parent',
  // ...
})
export class ParentComponent {
  constructor(protected cd: ChangeDetectorRef) {}
}
```

If you are using an abstract class as parent, you have to use an empty `@Directive()` decorator.

Comment: the parent is component and actually I cannot change it.

for adding ChangeDetectorRef in the providers, I've tried to add and I got this 


`Type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'Provider'.
  Type 'typeof ChangeDetectorRef' is not assignable to type 'TypeProvider'.
    Cannot assign an abstract constructor type to a non-abstract constructor type.`

Comment: @EmadAldinBaybars using providers is not the way to do it indeed. You don't need to change the parent to be not component. So you can extend it as I've showed in my updated answer. However it feels like you should extract the common code, and place this in an abstract class, and extend this both from the Child as Parent component

Comment: the thing I'm trying to do is extending the Angular kendo grid and one of its dependencies is the `ChangeDetectorRef` . when I'm trying to provide it in the super call it gives me the error I mentioned before.

Comment: @EmadAldinBaybars you should probably share you code, to have a better understanding of what you are trying to do. Always nice to provide all necessary information when asking a question :)

Comment: What do you think ?

Comment: @EmadAldinBaybars do you think you'll be able to create a stackblitz with your issue? Because adding it to the `super()` call should work, and should not give such an error